# can't open jupyter notebook in new conda environment on windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Edit: This seem to be a conda-forge issue. `conda install jupyter` works fine. Opened issue on GitHub: https://github.com/conda-forge/jupyter-feedstock/issues/6

Long time python Mac user. First time python windows users (windows 7 enterprise).

Installed python via Anaconda (https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe)

Jupyter notebook works fine in the base environment.

When I create a new environment I cannot open jupyter notebook.

Open Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda create -n test_env2 python=3.6
conda activate test_env2
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

When I open an Ipython notebook it shows 'Kernel error': 
[image]

and the obvious errors are:

```
[E 18:53:32.420 NotebookApp] Failed to run command:
['C:/Users/131416/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/test_env2/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\131416\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-99e95812-0a80-4772-94fc-e35563ce58e1.json']

  File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib\subprocess.py", 
line 997, in _execute_child
   startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

[E 18:53:32.498 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/sessions (::1) 135.50ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
```

Perhaps it has something to do with it picking up `jupyter.exe` in the base environment as well as the `jupyter.exe` in the new environment:
[image]

There is also some discussion in https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2130 but the solutions aren't obvious.

The full Traceback is (apologies for the layout. Copied from cmd):

> (test_env2) C:\Users\131416>jupyter notebook [I 18:53:24.082
>   NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\13 1416
>   [I 18:53:24.084 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: [I
>   18:53:24.085 NotebookApp]
>   http://localhost:8888/?token=2ecb94399a83d9dc1f8f11
>   6e0f28a46e297033c1fd796e23 [I 18:53:24.086 NotebookApp] Use Control-C
>   to stop this server and shut down all  kernels (twice to skip
>   confirmation). [C 18:53:24.089 NotebookApp]
>
> ```
> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
> to login with a token:
>     http://localhost:8888/?token=2ecb94399a83d9dc1f8f116e0f28a46e297033c1fd7
> ```
>
> 96e23 [I 18:53:24.384 NotebookApp] Accepting
>   one-time-token-authenticated connection f rom ::1 [W 18:53:31.615
>   NotebookApp] 404 GET /undefined (::1) 12.00ms referer=None [I
>   18:53:31.631 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in [E 18:53:32.420
>   NotebookApp] Failed to run command:
>       ['C:/Users/131416/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/test_env2/bin/pytho
>   n', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f',
>   'C:\Users\131416\AppData\Roaming\jupy
>   ter\runtime\kernel-99e95812-0a80-4772-94fc-e35563ce58e1.json']
>           PATH='C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tes
>   t_env2;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\
>   \Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
>   \envs\test_env2\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuu
>   m\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\Library\bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\C
>   ontinuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\Scripts;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\
>   \Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\C
>   ontinuum\anaconda3;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib
>   rary\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Li
>   brary\usr\bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library
>   \bin;C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users
>   \131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\bin;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ca\
>   \sc\CAWIN\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\w
>   indows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.
>   0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program
>   Files (x8 6)\IBM\Client Access\Emulator;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Sh ared;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IBM\Client Access\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebE
>   x\Productivity Tools;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\CA\SC\Csam\SockAdapter\bin;c: \Program Files
>   (x86)\CA\SC\Csam\SockAdapter\bin64;c:\Program Files (x86)\
>   \ca\sc\CBB\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ca\DSM\bin;c:\PROGRA~2\ca\sc\CAM\ bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel
>   \WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin'
>           with kwargs:
>       {'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': 'C:\Users\131416'}
>
> [E 18:53:32.441 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception POST /api/sessions
>   (::1)
>       HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='POST', uri
>   ='/api/sessions', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
>           result = yield result
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in
>   post
>           type=mtype))
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79,
>   in create
>   _session
>           kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
>           yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92,
>   in start_ kernel_for_session
>           self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_na me)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
>           value = future.result()
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
>           yielded = next(result)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 160,
>   in start_k ernel
>           super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in
>   start_kernel
>           km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
>           **kw)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
>           return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
>           proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \subprocess.py", line 709, in **init**
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "C:\Users\131416\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env2\lib
>   \subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
>           startupinfo)
>       FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified [W 18:53:32.480 NotebookApp] Unhandled error [E 18:53:32.482
>   NotebookApp] {
>         "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         "X-Xsrftoken": "2|d69ec7c3|9a70043f110f803ee6ab3273dd14309a|1538153699",
>         "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
>         "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=pyt hon3",
>         "Accept-Language": "en-US",
>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
>         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) l ike Gecko",
>         "Host": "localhost:8888",
>         "Content-Length": "91",
>         "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
>         "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
>         "Cookie": "username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1538175204|23:username-local
>   host-8888|44:Y2MwOTgzODhmZDZhNGE4NzhmM2Q2NWJjMDI2MjVjZjc=|a3c49f08f13669a523498b
>   9125cf42ce7eaab53181c1441544fcf533a94545da\";
>   _xsrf=2|d69ec7c3|9a70043f110f803ee 6ab3273dd14309a|1538153699; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1538162170|23:use
>   rname-localhost-8889|44:NWQzZWQwZDY3ZmMzNDAzM2I5NDI4ZWI5OTA5NTkwZDc=|d515096d015
>   d24b1e06638fa64fc2c7b145a17c411203fd4141733f0a7815b9a\";
>   username-localhost-8890
>   =\"2|1:0|10:1538162261|23:username-localhost-8890|44:YTU3NmY5MDczNzNmNGNjMTg1MzU
>   yYjkyODU3ZDE5Y2I=|342bc9d819999a050780d4dbef1f9ade1e69fe3f52914132a9b897a0f3023a
>   f2\""
>       } [E 18:53:32.498 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/sessions (::1) 135.50ms referer=http: //localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 [I
>   18:55:32.687 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb

Answer (score 11):

After activating the environment, please install ipykernel

```
conda install ipykernel
```

and then run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems to be a conda-forge issue as opposed to a conda issue (question edited)

Answer (score 1):

Activate the new envirionment and then Install jupyter

```
conda install ipykernel
pip3 install jupyter
```

Then install the required libraries using conda and pip for working on your project

Comment: after that i got error:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help you much but in-case if you are using **Docker**, you can do the following:

1. Create a Dockerfile with the following content

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook

RUN pip install -U pip

ENV JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes

COPY --chown=${NB_UID}:${NB_GID} . /home/vishesh/work
WORKDIR /home/vishesh/work

CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--notebook-dir=/home/vishesh/work", "--allow-root"]
```

2. Create docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  jupyterlab:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/home/vishesh/work
```

3. Both the files should be in the same folder
4. Open PowerShell in the current directory and below commands in sequence
   `docker-compose build`
   `docker-compose up`
5. Once all the services start to appear running in PowerShell window.
   Go to your browser and open http://localhost:8888

This is just to demonstrate that how easy it could be directly using virtualization option rather that installing everything on your own.

Answer (score -1):

```
conda activate new_env_name
```

to activate under MacOS

```
source activate new_ene_name
```

under Windows